# WebDriver Java "Http/1.1 Service Unavailable" error

Tags: java, selenium

The following Java logs on, but results in the `"Http/1.1 Service unavailable"` error page being displayed:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() ;
WebElement element = null ;
driver.get("http://www.icloud.com/#contacts") ;
// wait for page to load...with desired element
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return driver.findElement(By.className("username")) != null ;
    }
});
element = driver.findElement(By.className("username"));   // Apple id
element.sendKeys("username@icloud.com");
element = driver.findElement(By.className("password"));   // Password
element.sendKeys("userpassword");
element.submit();
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
```

Do you know what could be wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
element.submit();
```

You should use

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

For which you need to one additional import as below-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
```